# How do I disable remote debugging

Tags: java, java-8, remote-debugging

Currently I start up a Java Virtual Machine with the following command line arguments

```
-Xint -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=4000,suspend=n
```

This allows me to attach a debugger to that JVM with both JVM and debugger on the same machine. However it also allows the remote debugging of that session.  My system adminstrator points out to me that this can be insecure and doesn't want me to do that.

But which command line arguments do I need to change so I can attach a debugger on the local machine to that JVM, just not a remote one?

I'm using Java 8 but happy to migrate to Java 9 if that's what it takes.

Comment: If you're on Windows you could also use `dt_shmem` instead of `dt_socket` to debug via shared memory (which will only work if the JVM and the debugger are on the same machine) IIRC, but I never used it myself, so......

Comment: I believe Java 9's default behavior is to limit connections to the "localhost" interface only, so you can only connect from the same box.  You need to explicitly inform it if you want to open that port on all interfaces.  So in Java 9, the default behavior is what you want.

Comment: I have to admit, I do not get the pun about your nickname. Is it like p45... The 45th president of the United States? Thus you consider yourself that "low"? If so, don't do that. You are polite, you acknowledge when you don't know something. Thus you are way better than said sad excuse of a human being.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write your local adress before the port like this:

```
-Xint -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=127.0.0.1:4000,suspend=n
```

as wildcard for access from every adress, you could also use:

```
-Xint -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=0.0.0.0:4000,suspend=n
```

Comment: So it's always `127.0.0.1`? And to recover the current behaviour I should use `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: To answer your question directly: the adress 127.0.0.1 always "points" to your local maschine. To recover current behaviour you can use 0.0.0.0, or just use the port like before.
For further readings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: @GhostCat: Am I living up to my name?